# Laravel - Error Messages not showing on blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

`i will show my code, everything was working fine i suddenly noticed the messages are not displaying anywhere in my pages not just this page.

```
 public function userPass(Request $request, $id)
     {
 
         /* $request->validate([
         'current_password' => ['required', new MatchOldPassword],
         'new_password' => ['required'],
         'new_confirm_password' => ['same:new_password'],
         ]);
         */
         $check = Hash::check($request->current_password, auth()->user()->password);
         if ($check == true) {
             User::find(auth()->user()->id)->update(['password' => Hash::make($request->new_password)]);
             return redirect()->route('userSettings')->with('success', '!تم تغير كلمة المرور بنجاح');
         } else
             return redirect()->route('userSettings')->with('warning', '.كلمة المرور الحالية غير متطابقة');
  }
    
 


@extends('layout.userinterface')
@section('content')
    <style>
        #navbar {
            box-shadow: 0 0.3rem 2rem rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
            max-height: 100% !important;
        }

        .nav-container {
            height: 100% !important;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Orders section start -->
    <section class="user-settings">
        <div class="settings-container">
            <h2>حسابي</h2>
            <hr>
            <form action="{{ route('userSettingsUpdate', [$user->id]) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="relative">
                    <input type="text" disabled name="name" value="{{ Auth()->user()->name }}" id="floating_outlined"
                        class="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border-1 border-gray-300 appearance-none dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer"
                        placeholder=" " />
                    <label for="floating_outlined"
                        class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 duration-300 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 px-2 peer-focus:px-2  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 left-1">الاسم
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="relative">
                    <input type="email" disabled name="email" value="{{ Auth()->user()->email }}" id="floating_outlined"
                        class="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border-1 border-gray-300 appearance-none dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer"
                        placeholder=" " />
                    <label for="floating_outlined"
                        class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 duration-300 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 px-2 peer-focus:px-2  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 left-1">البريد
                        الإلكتروني</label>
                </div>
                <div class="relative">
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" value="{{ Auth()->user()->phone }}" id="floating_outlined"
                        class="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border-1 border-gray-300 appearance-none dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer"
                        placeholder=" " />
                    <label for="floating_outlined"
                        class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 duration-300 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 px-2 peer-focus:px-2 peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 left-1">رقم
                        الهاتف</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">حفظ التغيرات</button>
            </form>
            <h2>كلمة السر</h2>
            <hr>

            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <p class="parentErrorMessage">{{ $error }}</p>
            @endforeach

            @include('home.messages')

            <form id="passwordForm" action="{{ route('userSettingsUpdatePass', [$user->id]) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf

                <div class="relative">
                    <input type="password" name="current_password" id="currentPassword" onfocusout="validateOldPassword()"
                        class="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border-1 border-gray-300 appearance-none dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer"
                        placeholder=" " />
                    <label for="currentPassword"
                        class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 duration-300 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 px-2 peer-focus:px-2  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 left-1">كلمة
                        المرور الحالية</label>
                </div>
                <p class="errorMessage mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 dark:text-red-400"></p>
                <div class="relative">
                    <input type="password" name="new_password" id="newPassword" onfocusout="validateNewPassword()"
                        class="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border-1 border-gray-300 appearance-none dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer"
                        placeholder=" " />
                    <label for="newPassword"
                        class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 duration-300 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 px-2 peer-focus:px-2  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 left-1">كلمة
                        المرور الجديدة</label>
                </div>
                <p class="errorMessage mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 dark:text-red-400"></p>
                <button type="submit">حفظ التغيرات</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- orders section end -->
    <script src="{{ asset('assets') }}/js/formValidation.js"></script>
@endsection
```

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="parentSuccessMessage">
        
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif


@if ($message = Session::get('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif

@if ($message = Session::get('wrong'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
       
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif


@if ($message = Session::get('warning'))
    <div class="p-3 mb-4 text-sm text-center text-yellow-1000 rounded-lg bg-yellow-50 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-yellow-300" style="max-width:400px; border-radius:10px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-itmes:center; margin-bottom:35px;" role="alert">
       
        <strong style="text-align:left">{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif


@if ($message = Session::get('info'))
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" disabled aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ $message}}
    </div>
@endif
```

i tried using flush into session, didn't work i tried put::session . also didn't work even tho when i use
dd($request->session()) i can see the messages in the flush section. but in my blade nothing is working.`

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache by running `php artisan optimize:clear` ?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried but nah it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

The errors didn't show up because you use session, not validation. If you try to get the session and the message change your code to this

> ```
> @if(Session::has('success'))
>     <div class="parentSuccessMessage">
>         <strong>{{ Session::get('success') }}</strong>
>     </div>
> @endif
> ```